# Hibernate Reverse Engineering Using CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy class to remove catalog name

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have extended `org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy` class for custom reverse engineering using hibernate tools library and ant script.
After running ant script, classes are getting generated as -

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account"
    ,catalog="testdb"
)

public class Account  implements java.io.Serializable {
}
```

In above class **`catalog`** name is always getting added in generated class.

I am trying to remove catalog name using CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy.java class. 
Here is my java class -

```
public class CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

 public Map<String, MetaAttribute> tableToMetaAttributes(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier){
        Map<String, MetaAttribute> metaAttributes = super.tableToMetaAttributes(tableIdentifier);

        if (metaAttributes == null) {
            metaAttributes = new HashMap<String, MetaAttribute>();
         }

        String catalogName = tableIdentifier.getCatalog();      
        if(metaAttributes.containsKey(catalogName)){
            System.out.print(catalogName);
            metaAttributes.remove(catalogName);         
        }
        return metaAttributes;
    }
}
```

In this tableIdentifier returns catalog name. But, there is no method to set catalog name.
Also metaAttributes does not contain key for catalog name.

I want to remove this catalog name in class generation process using CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy  class. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using maven-replacer-plugin.

Maybe that's not what you are asking, but it works.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>(version)</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>replace</goal>
                </goals>                    
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <regex>false</regex>
            <token>,catalog="testdb"</token>
            <value></value>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```